# Javascript search using show() and hide() and adding additional classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using javascript to search through a group of divs while I type. It displays the divs if their title matches what is being typed in the search box and hides any that don't match.

I want to also make the displayed divs have a position of 'initial' instead of 'absolute' so that they move to the top of the page if they are being shown.

I have tried the code below (the line: $('.cbp-item').position='initial';) but it doesn't add the attribute.

I don't seem to get any js errors in the console either.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#societies_search').on('keyup',function(){
        var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        if(valThis == ""){
            $('.cbp-item').show();
            $('.cbp-item').position='initial';
        }
        else {
            $('.cbp-item').each(function(i,item){
                var text = $(item).text().toLowerCase();
                console.log($(item).find('a').text());
                if(text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) {
                    $(item).show();
                    $(item).position='initial';
                }
                else{
                    $(item).hide();
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: use this $(item).css("position","initial");

Comment: What classes are being added?

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution how can I remove it again when the text is deleted from the search box? So all divs should go back to show they were before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.css()` for this

```
$(item).css('position','initial');
```

Comment: hi, thank you. how do i remove this again if the text in the search box is removed?

Comment: you can remove all attribute using 'removeAttr()' or if you want to set another value of this attribute then you can use same code `$(item).css('position','initial');`